# Login after installing plugins

Tags: impresspages

after installing these plugins:

1. Concatenate Js/Css and
2. SimpleCache

I get this error in backend:

```
    Error: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
```

I have this behaviour at two sites. Other sites without these plugins are working. 
How can I reach the backend or what have I to do to reach the backend?

Regards
Uwe

Answer (score 0):

turn on safe mode: http://www.impresspages.org/docs/safe-mode/
It turns off all plugins.

You also make plugins inactive by going to the database and altering ip_plugin table records.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for support. I've got the problem, that I can't reach the backend.
In your doc is written:

*Safe mode can be used only by the administrator. Make sure you are logged in to the admin before trying to enter safe mode. - See more at: http://www.impresspages.org/docs/safe-mode/#sthash.1wgnuAaq.dpuf*

Well, I can't enter the backend. When I'm typing: www.http://domain.tld/admin I get the error above. Is there a fault on my side?

Is it possible to rename or delete the both plugin-folders via ftp to get than access to the backend?

*You also make plugins inactive by going to the database and altering ip_plugin table records.* Okay, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Plugin has been updated. Should work now.